# Arrow to add one element at a time

Tags: xml, haskell, arrows, hxt, monoids

This question is about HXT, but I guess it's applicable to conception of
`ArrowPlus` in general. Consider the following program:

```hs
module Main (main) where

import Text.XML.HXT.Core
import Control.Monad (void)

main :: IO ()
main = void $ runX $ root [] [foo]
       >>> writeDocument [withIndent yes] "test.xml"

foo :: ArrowXml a => a XmlTree XmlTree
foo = selem "foo" [bar >>> bar >>> bar]

bar :: ArrowXml a => a XmlTree XmlTree
bar = this <+> eelem "bar"
```

Can you tell what will be saved in `test.xml`? My expectations:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
  <bar/>
  <bar/>
  <bar/>
</foo>
```

My logic: arrow `bar` copies all its input and adds one ‘bar’ element
(`this` is alias for identity arrow):

```
 |     |
this  eelem "bar"
 |     |
 \     /
  \   /
   <+>
    |
```

So, result of `bar >>> bar >>> bar` should be three ‘bar’ elements (note
that `eelem "bar" >>> eelem "bar"` will result in only one ‘bar’ element,
since arrows of `mkelem` family ignore their input (although it still can be
used to generate their contents) and output only newly created element).

Having said all that, I present contents of `test.xml` after execution of
the program:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
  <//>
  <bar/>
  <bar/>
  <bar/>
  <bar/>
  <bar/>
  <bar/>
  <bar/>
</foo>
```

Questions:

1. What is `<//>`?
2. Why there are 7 ‘bar’ elements instead of 3? What is reason of this
   duplication?
3. Why when I replace `bar >>> bar >>> bar` with `none >>> bar >>> bar >>>
   bar` I get:

```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <foo/>
```

where `none` is zero arrow. We deal with monoid on arrows here, right?
   `none` (≡ `zeroArrow`) should be identity for it, so it should go like:
   `none <+> eelem "bar"` which produces a ‘bar’ element and subsequent
   calls should add two another elements. But we don't get any!

4. How to write proper version of `bar` arrow that would add one ‘bar’
   element at a time?

Sorry for asking 4 questions, but I guess they are closely related, so it
shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have some confusion between how the `>>>` and `<+>` operators work. To build intuition, let's first define two different `bar`s:

```
bar1 :: ArrowXml a => a XmlTree XmlTree
bar1 = this <+> eelem "bar"

bar2 :: ArrowXml a => a n XmlTree
bar2 = eelem "bar"
```

The first thing we notice is the type signature. `bar1` has an input type of `XmlTree`, meaning that it modifies an existing tree in some way, whereas `bar2` discards its argument. This is due to the use of `this` in `bar1` that copies its elements. Now, let's load these up in `ghci` to figure out how `>>>` and `<+>` work together:

```
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> runX $ xshow $ bar2
["<bar/>"]
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> runX $ xshow $ bar2 >>> bar2 >>> bar2
["<bar/>"]
```

Hm, that's weird, it keeps creating the same structure no matter how many times we compose it with `>>>`. This happens because for `bar2`, we're discarding the tree each time we transform it: remember it's type signature is `a n XmlTree` instead of `a XmlTree XmlTree`. Let's compare that to `bar1`:

```
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> runX $ xshow $ bar1
["<//><bar/>"]
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> runX $ xshow $ bar1 >>> bar1
["<//><bar/><bar/><bar/>"]
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> runX $ xshow $ bar1 >>> bar1 >>> bar1
["<//><bar/><bar/><bar/><bar/><bar/><bar/><bar/>"]
```

Woah, it's growing exponentially! Why? Well, each time you compose with `>>>`, you're taking the previous tree, and for each element applying the function application `this <+> eelem "bar"`. The first invocation of `bar1` has no previous tree, so `this` becomes the root node and you simply append an element of `<bar/>` to it. However, for `bar1 >>> bar1`, the first `bar1` will create `<//><bar/>` and the second one will compose each node of `<//><bar/>` with `bar1` again, leading to:

```
bar1 === <//><bar/>
bar1 >>> bar1 === <//><bar/><bar/><bar/>
                  |--------||----------|
                    First      Second
```

Now you keep doing that, and you can see how `bar1 >>> bar1 >>> bar1` will produce seven `<bar/>`s preceded by a `<//>`.

OK, so now that we have intuition for `>>>` in terms of `ArrowXml` we can see how `<+>` behaves:

```
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> runX $ xshow $ bar2 <+> bar2 <+> bar2
["<bar/><bar/><bar/>"]
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> runX $ xshow $ bar1 <+> bar1 <+> bar1
["<//><bar/><//><bar/><//><bar/>"]
```

Oh, that's pretty simple... they just append one after the other. We can see that the type of `bar1 <+> bar1` is still one that transforms values of type `a XmlTree XmlTree`, so you will get some crazy behavior if you combine it with `>>>`. See if you can wrap your mind around this output:

```
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> runX $ xshow $ (bar1 <+> bar1) >>> bar1
["<//><bar/><bar/><bar/><//><bar/><bar/><bar/>"]
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> runX $ xshow $ bar1 >>> (bar1 <+> bar1)
["<//><bar/><//><bar/><bar/><bar/><bar/><bar/>"]
```

To answer your question about `none`, check it's type signature:

```
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> :t none
none :: ArrowList a => a b c
```

To me that says it takes a value of type `b` and returns a value of type `c`. Since we have no idea what `c` is (we didn't provide it as an argument to `none`), we can assume that it's going to be the empty set. This makes sense with our previous definitions of `>>>` and `<+>`:

```
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> runX $ xshow $ none <+> bar1
["<//><bar/>"]
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> runX $ xshow $ none >>> bar1
[""]
```

In the first case, the empty document appended with another document is basically the identity operation. In the second one, `none` produces no elements, so when you *compose* it with `bar1`, there are no elements to operate on, and hence the result is the empty document. In fact, since Haskell is lazy we can be even more cavalier about what we compose with `none` since we know that it'll never be evaluated:

```
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> runX $ xshow $ none >>> undefined
[""]
```

Given this knowledge, what you were probably trying to do was something like this:

```
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> let bar = eelem "bar"
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> runX $ xshow $ selem "foo" [bar <+> bar <+> bar]
["<foo><bar/><bar/><bar/></foo>"]
```

#### EDIT

A similar solution is to use the `+=` operator:

```
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> let bars = replicate 3 (eelem "bar")
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> runX $ xshow $ foldl (+=) (eelem "foo") bars
["<foo><bar/><bar/><bar/></foo>"]
```

Comment: This is a great answer, I appreciate your explanation a lot. Indeed, I forgot about this aspect of HXT arrows. It seems silly now. However, `bar <+> bar <+> bar` is obvious solution, I knew it before. My question is how to write an arrow `bar`, so when I write `bar >>> bar >>> bar` I get three bar elements, this arrow should add one element at a time. I guess there should be special arrows for it. If you know how to do it, please add it to your answer.

Comment: In reality, content is built this way `none >>> bar >>> bar >>> bar`. Not every `bar` actually adds something, first `bar` that adds elements also should add thing `X`. Subsequent `bar`s see that `X` exists in their input and they know that `X` is already added, so they add `X'`. Not sure that this is the best explanation.

Comment: Content cannot be built using `none >>> ...` as I showed using `undefined`. With that in mind, you cannot add a single element at a time using `>>>`, since you're composing over all of the elements in a given node. `>>>` is useful if you'd like to e.g. add an attribute to each element or populate each element with additional nodes.

Comment: Right... Is it possible at all to add one element at a time using some other function / operator? Bad thing about `bar <+> bar <+> bar` is that every `bar` has no idea if other `bar` has already added element `X` or not, because every `bar` gets the same input. I guess I have to resort to manual controlling of the situation...

Comment: Sure, try this: `eelem "foo" += eelem "bar"  += eelem "bar"  += eelem "bar"`

Comment: Great. So, new plan goes like this: select "foo" element, delete all its children, then use `+=` operator to generate new content. Please add a few words about `+=` operator, so for the benefit of future readers. I think now I can finish my work. Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell why `foo = foldl (+=) (eelem "foo") [bar,bar,bar]` and `bar = ifA (deep (hasName "bar")) (eelem "baz") (eelem "bar")` produce `<foo><bar/><bar/><bar/></foo>`, not `<foo><bar/><baz/><baz/></foo>`. I think it has to do with input values of `bar` arrow. Maybe it's not updated after each step. Sorry for so many questions...

Comment: That should be asked in a separate question as it doesn't relate to the specific problem outlined in this one.