# Stubbornness of += operator

Tags: xml, haskell, hxt

As we have learned from [my previous
question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30029001/arrow-to-add-one-element-at-a-time),
[`+=`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.15/docs/Text-XML-HXT-Arrow-XmlArrow.html#v:-43--61-)
is the operator that allows to add one element at a time. Is it possible to
«detect» previously added elements and control how future additions are
done?

Here is a simple program to start our investigation:

```hs
module Main (main) where

import Control.Monad (void)
import Text.XML.HXT.Core

main :: IO ()
main = void $ runX $ root [] [foo]
       >>> writeDocument [withIndent yes] "test.xml"

foo :: ArrowXml a => a XmlTree XmlTree
foo = eelem "foo" += bar += bar += bar -- += is left associative

bar :: ArrowXml a => a XmlTree XmlTree
bar = ifA (deep (hasName "bar")) (eelem "baz") (eelem "bar")
```

Here, `foo` creates ‘foo’ node and its contents. Contents are generated with
`bar` arrow, that's supposed to be smart enough to detect previously added
‘bar’ element, and change its behavior. Here we use `deep` for simplicity:
if ‘bar’ element is child of ‘foo’ element, it should be detected, no matter
how deep it is (`getChildren >>> hasName "bar"` should do the trick too).

So, expected contents of `test.xml` file are:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
  <bar/>
  <baz/>
  <baz/>
</foo>
```

It doesn't work, of course. Here is what I get:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
  <bar/>
  <bar/>
  <bar/>
</foo>
```

My questions:

1. Why ‘bar’ element cannot be detected by `bar` arrow?
2. How to detect it?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `processChildren` from http://www.fh-wedel.de/~si/HXmlToolbox/hdoc/Control-Arrow-ArrowTree.html`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those cases where type signatures really help. Stare for a second at the type signature:

```
(+=) :: (ArrowXml a) => a b XmlTree -> a b XmlTree -> a b XmlTree
```

First off, `ArrowXml` is a subclass of `Arrow`, which describes some sort of machinery taking some input to some output. You can think of it like a big factory with conveyor belts taking things to different machines, and we're building these factory machines and hence factories with functions. Three of the Arrow combinators, for example, are:

```
(&&&) :: (Arrow a) => a b c -> a b c' -> a b (c, c') |infixr 3|
  Fanout: send the input to both argument arrows and combine their output.

arr :: (Arrow a) => (b -> c) -> a b c
  Lift a function to an arrow.

(.) :: (Category cat) => cat b c -> cat a b -> cat a c
  morphism composition.
```

Now look at the lowercase letter (type variable) very closely in:

```
(+=) :: (ArrowXml a) => a b XmlTree -> a b XmlTree -> a b XmlTree
```

Clearly we're taking two machines which turn `b`s into `XmlTree`s and "merging them together" into one machine which takes a `b` in and expels an `XmlTree`. But importantly, this type signature tells us that more or less the **only** way that this can be implemented is:

```
arr1 += arr2 = arr f . (arr1 &&& arr2) where
    f :: (XmlTree, XmlTree) -> XmlTree
    f = _
```

This is because of "free theorems"; if you don't know the type of a parameter then we can prove that you can't really *do* much with it. (It can be a little more complicated because the arrow might have structures which aren't totally encapsulated by `arr`, like internal counters which are summed together with `.` which are then set to `0` when using `arr`. So actually replace `arr f` with a generic `a (XmlTree, XmlTree) XmlTree` and you're good to go.)

So we must have **parallel execution** of the two arrows here. That's what I'm trying to say. Because the combinator `(+=)` doesn't know what `b` is, it has no choice but to blithely feed the `b` to the arrows in parallel and then try to combine their outputs together. So, `deep (hasName "bar")` does not look at `foo`.

You can possibly make a mutually recursive solution with `deep (hasName "bar") . foo` if you really want, but it seems potentially dangerous (i.e. infinite loop), so it may be safer to simply define something like:

```
a ++= b = a += (b . a)
```

where the "current" a is "fed" to b to produce the update. To do this you will have to import `.` from `Control.Category` as it is not the same as `Prelude..` (which does function composition only). This looks like:

```
import Prelude hiding ((.))
import Control.Category ((.))
```

Comment: Great, I works! Although I prefer `>>>` over `.` (from `Control.Category`).

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution that works, thanks to @ChrisDrost:

```hs
infixl 7 ++=

(++=) :: ArrowXml a => a XmlTree XmlTree -> a XmlTree XmlTree ->
         a XmlTree XmlTree
a ++= b = a += (a >>> b)
```

In my understanding, `+=` just pass its input around, since it has type `b`,
so it can't do much with it anyway. So, it just goes through the chain of
the operators unchanged. Here we put stronger constraint on that input of
`++=` can be: it must be an `XmlArrow`. We feed this arrow to the second
argument of `++=`, so it knows about «updated» state of XML document.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess: an `ArrowXml` is intended to take an XML tree as input and produce an XML tree as output. `hasName` queries the input; `eelem` modifies the output. I would be very surprised to find there was a way to query the output or modify the input.

On the other hand, the `arrows` package seems to offer a [stateful arrow transformer](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arrows-0.4.4.1/docs/Control-Arrow-Transformer-State.html) that may be useful. Presumably you could write an `instance ArrowXml a => ArrowXml (StateArrow s a)`.